# Can't connect to remote Spark Cluster via Java Program

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to connect to a remote Spark cluster via Java Program.
The Spark version is `1.6.2`

I did try to get a SparkSession using below code

```
SparkSession sparkSession= 
SparkSession.builder().master("somepath").appName("SparkJavaPOC").getOrCreate();
```

But facing

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/apache/spark/internal/Logging

at runtime. I have imported `spark-core_2.11-1.5.2` jar and read somewhere that org/apache/spark/internal/Logging is no more available with spark-core.

I need a solution by which I can connect to the Spark cluster without changing the spark Version via the Java program.

Comment: How are you building/packaging your code?

Comment: @Ernest Kiwele Not using any packaging tool, just trying to do a POC via a simple Java program

Comment: The dependency tree for spark doesn't end with spark-core. You need to include all transitive dependencies as well. You could try by adding libs that come with spark, but it's simply a good idea to use a build tool like maven or gradle.

Comment: @Ernest Kiwele Did try installing all dependencies using Maven ..still no luck

Comment: Can you elaborate on _"I have imported spark-core_2.11-1.5.2 jar"_? What did you do?